# Connection faliure to the server in jQuery Ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to identify an error during submitting Ajax request via jQuery when the connection to the server is failed. I load the page from the server, then disconnect the network connection. The following error handle in the Ajax jquery is used:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error){
          var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
         alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
          alert('Connection Error\nCould not connect to the server.');
          $("#loading").removeClass("show");
          $("#submit_btn").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
```

The first alert prints out:

```
Error - 0: error
```

I could not able to evaluate the returned errors values to identify the error cause is due to connection failure or something else!

Comment: Check the request in the network tab of the console. That gives you every piece of information about the request, from the headers and data sent to the response status code and error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status) say that an error code of `0` basically means the request could not be completed, while other errors could be due to request completing but some other error in the endpoint or with response.

So usually with the error code `0` you can assume that there was a network issue.